# How to publish a game on steam as a company?

Tags: steam

I have noticed people put games on steam like http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=627434907 where you see the developer profile but how do I get one like http://store.steampowered.com/app/71340/ where it's just a game and the publisher information at the bottom?

Comment: Your title question is much too broad. And the body of your question isn't really a question.

Answer (score 2):

The first link that you are seeing is a greenlight game that it isnt released yet. So the process is: As an Indie Developer, you put your game in the greenlight, after that community shows interest and then you can release your game, you'll get a game page as that one with just the game and the publisher infos, a standard one.